# Can I register a BROADCAST RECEIVER and unregister it in another activty? - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

It causes a window leak.

Let me explain the scenario, 
->My application has an ACTIVITY_A for the user to 'sign up' and upon submit I trigger an OTP to the User's device.

-> After sign up the user is redirected to ACTIVITY_B where he/she verifies the OTP.
I'd like to catch the OTP using a "SMS receiver" and unregister it after it meets its purpose.

If I start the receiver in ACTIVTY_B, will there be a possibility I could miss the SMS I was hoping to catch?
Could somebody please tell me an appropriate way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

make a base activity class and extend it in both the activities
handle both register and un-register receiver in base activity

this is how i have implemented it